# Howto display the exit code of an Equinox application from within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, equinox, exit-code

With Eclipse Equinox, an application implements `IApplication` and gets its `start` method called.  The return value of this method is the return value of the application.  If I start the application (through Equinox) from the command line, the exit code is set corretly.

Now, how can I see/retrieve the exit code if I'm starting the application from Eclipse?  I'm setting up a run configuration and let the application run. All output on `System.out` and `System.err` is correctly shown in the Console.  But (unlike a real console) after the application terminates I cannot enter things like `echo $?` and `echo %errorlevel%` to get the exit code.  How to do that?

Comment: Workaround: print it to the console before returning?

Comment: Well, yes. I'm doing that. But how to do it right? And there might be `exit` statements sprinkled in code. It's clumsy to add and remove print statments for all of them.